# Limit the number of visits per vehicle in a Vehicle Routing Problem

Tags: optaplanner

I am using optaplanner to solve a vehicle routing problem and I have the following constraints:

- Each vehicle must attend a minimum number of visits. The vehicle must not leave the depot until it has this minimum number of visits. Therefore, a route where the vehicle is assigned fewer visits than the minimum number required should not be considered as a feasible solution.
- Similarly, each vehicle must attend a maximum number of visits. The vehicle should not leave the depot with more visits than the maximum number of visits allowed. Therefore, a route where the vehicle is assigned more visits than the maximum number required should not be considered a feasible solution.

Is it possible to limit the range of Planning Visits that can be assigned to a Planning Vehicle Entity during the scoring calculation?
In this way it would be possible to assign a minimum and maximum number of visits per vehicle.

My question would be How to ensure that these restrictions are enforced in VRP?
I have thought that maybe the way is with constraint provider, but it may be something more complicated related to index in move. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry for the wording, I am a Spanish speaker.

Answer (score 0):

For max, use a hard constraint.

The trick is to use a medium constraint for min, or a low-weighted hard constraint, so it will prefer breaking the minimum constraint on a new vehicle over breaking the max constraints on another vehicle. That will entice it to use more vehicles (which will lead it to a feasible solution) instead of going of the max of the current vehicles (which will get it stuck in an infeasible solution).

Also, avoid a score trap (see docs) by penalizing the lacking number of visits.

```
from(Visit.class)
.groupBy(Visit::getVehicle, count())
.filter(... -> vehicle.getMinimum() > count)
.penalize("min", HardMediumSoftLongScore.ONE_MEDIUM, ... -> vehicle.getMinimum() - count)
```

Same impl principle for max.